# Ubuntu doesn't show install along side option

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

Currently my entire Windows 10 is in one partition on C: yes I know past me was dumb.

Originally I had wanted to move Win10 to a new SSD and dual boot form there. (See above)

My main HDD is 4TB that isn't quite half full so figured dual booting form there would be fine but when installing Ubuntu it doesn't show the option to install along side Windows. It shows the HDD and the current partitions when I select other install options.

I am aware that starting from scratch and installing Win10 to my SSD and the Ubuntu would possibly solve this but really don't want to reinstall 1TB of steam games, That I'll probably never play.

The HDD is 4 TB and has been cloned in the past, at least three times. When I try to migrate the Win OS from the HDD to SSD using AOMEI it says I can not go to the 120 GB SSD because it needs 1.5 TB which lead me down the road of having to redo everything just to boot from the SSD. I decided that it wasn't that important. So I was going to simply dual boot off of the HDD and split it in half, 2 TB for Win and 2 TB for Linux. However Ubuntu installer only shows me the options to erase everything or custom options, sorry forget the exact words it uses.

Comment: You've provided no release details; but I'd check you have *fast boot* and *hibernate* off on your windows system, as they leave an unclean file-system on the disk (parts of the *file-system* exists in fastboot or hibernate file) so that partition is IGNORED intentionally to prevent data loss; meaning only a ERASE option should be expected.   *Being specific with details is helpful; what do you mean by see above? you mention Ubuntu installer without saying which installer (the ISO used dictates the installer you're talking about - but you didn't tell us, do you mean `ubiquity`, `subiquity`..)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the "Install alongside Windows" option for a guided installation, you need two things:

**1) You need enough unpartitioned free space to install Ubuntu.**

25 GB is the recommended minimum amount of space for Ubuntu Desktop, but it would be wise to allocate more space if you can afford it.  Do not use Windows' tools to create partitions for Ubuntu. If necessary, shrink your Windows partition. Consult Windows documentation/support if you need to shrink Windows. If you need to delete partitions or format disks, you can use the "Disks" application from the live session (Try Ubuntu when booting installation media). Making changes to partitions and installing operating systems can wipe or overwrite data, and it's easy to make mistakes so be careful what you do and make sure you have backups before you start.

**2) You need to boot the installation media using the same method that Windows is already installed.**

If Windows is installed as UEFI (most common), you must boot the USB as UEFI.  If Windows is installed as BIOS you must boot the USB without UEFI (sometimes this is called MBR, Legacy, or Compatibility).  If you aren't sure how to boot your USB this way, read the documentation for your motherboard, because instructions are not the same between manufacturers.

Comment: FYI:  I did a *impish* QA-test install today (*actually a number*); the first is full disk install, subsequent was a *install alongside* where no "*unpartitioned free space*" existed (*your wording*), but the installer created the required space by shrinking the partition created in my prior QA-test install.  (*I did another subsequent install after this.. but point made*).. alas today for me was Lubuntu only (so `calamares` but I do the same installs using `ubiquity` somewhat often).  You might need to adjust heading/wording

Comment: OP says the HDD has been cloned a few times. If this is an old MBR/BIOS based install of Windows, and already has 4 primary partitions, then ubiquity won't give you the option to install alongside, even if you shrink a partition and create "unused free space".